# Inlining typescript functions

Tags: typescript, inline

Is there any library that does inlining of functions? 
Not sure if I am describing in the right terms, but let me add an example.

lets say I have the following code:

```
const addOne = number => {
  return number + 1;
};

const tempFunction = () => {
  const t = 41;
  return  {
    number: t,
    fn: addOne
  }
}
```

and I want to get back

```
const tempFunction = () => {
  const t = 41;
  return {
    number: t,
    fn: number => {
      return number + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this programmatically during build time?

Comment: You should also note that this can be dangerous. It's possible (easy, even) to write a function that would behave differently after being inlined than it did before.

Comment: @CRice,  I understand that this can be dangerous. But I really need to serialize some functions. I can easily serialize/deserialize in the inlined format, but with function identifiers, it stringify does not go into nested funcs.